# Emgu CV SURFFeature Error

Tags: computer-vision, emgucv

I downloaded the Emgu CV (Computer Vision) library and I'm just having a look at the SURFFeature example.

I'm trying to put two new images in to compare, instead of the examples given, but on this line I get an error with the new images:

```
Image<Gray, Byte> modelImage = new Image<Gray, byte>("me.png");
```

I get this exception:

**OpenCV: Array should be CvMat or IplImage**

I don't understand why it won't accept my image, any ideas anyone?

Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Emgu CV 2, and i wrote the same code, but there were no problem in my program.
If you also use this version, and stil have problem try this solution:

```cs
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("me.png");
    
    Image Gray, Byte> modelImage = new Image Gray, byte>(bmp);
```

Comment: Thanks! :)  It was a property of the images that I was using.  I found the solution.  But thanks for your input.

Question:  How are you finding dealing with all the maths involved using Computer Vision?